# Mix SSL certificates

Tags: ssl

I'd like to have a SSL certificate for domainA that load images from domainB (I load them from another cookieless domain to improve page speed). I know that all elements coming from domainB should be over SSL, but do i need to secure this second domain with a certificate coming from the same provider? I mean, could I mix a page with a ie verisign certificate with images coming over SSL from another domain with a different - and cheaper - certificate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will work and show no error in the browser. It's the same if you for example include Google Fonts (via e.g. https://fonts.googleapis.com) or Bing Maps using their SSL certificates. There shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Of course! I'm embarrassed for having asked this dumb question :)

Comment: @Sergi Never be embarrassed for asking :) Your question has now helped archived the answer for other curious people. It's the whole point of Stack Overflow!

Comment: I think it's actually a very good question! Is it fair to say that only the quality of the certificate of the initial request (fetching the HTML page itself) is what determines the certificate quality that the browser displays to users (green or grey URL bar)?

Comment: What happens if the main domain's certificate is EV (Green) and the cookieless domain certificate is not EV? Will the green status appear in the browser?